# Is it possible to proxy a database, in java?

Tags: java, sql, database, proxy

I have a specific need to audit queries made to databases. For this my idea is build a proxy on top of the database.

This proxy will do the monitoring before forwarding the SQL queries to the database.

I could not find any tool doing this, or any example on how to implement it.

Would somebody have some experience in this field and point me to the right direction?

Many thanks

Gilles

Comment: How are you accessing the database at the moment?

Comment: most "professionell" databases provide such feature by themselves (Oracle and MA-SQL-server for sure, MySQL maybe too...) can you change to one of them before creating your own auditing framework?

Comment: [P6Spy](https://p6spy.github.io/p6spy/) does this. Also [JavaMelody](https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/wiki/UserGuide).